# can anyone help to explain calldataload

Tags: solidity, assembly, calldata

In the Solidity documentation, the definition of `calldataload` is:

> calldataload(p) call data starting from position p (32 bytes)

But I am really confused by what is call data. Is the call data of the previous transaction or of the current call?

Say if we have a smart contract, we called `method1`, and then call `method2` which contains assembly with `calldataload`. Will this `calldataload` load the input of `method2` or `method1`?

Comment: thank you for answering, it is clearer now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.4/types.html):

> calldata is a special data location that contains the function arguments, only available for external function call parameters.
>
> Every reference type, i.e. arrays and structs, has an additional annotation, the “data location”, about where it is stored. There are three data locations: memory, storage and calldata. Calldata is only valid for parameters of external contract functions and is required for this type of parameter. Calldata is a non-modifiable, non-persistent area where function arguments are stored, and behaves mostly like memory.

Put simply, `calldata` is the input data to a transaction on a function. For example, if you look at [this](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x72afa9842ad5b9e83362bf46abf2cf8f6b0f1c7bff426810feba6dffcb0a1a6c) transaction, you will see that the `calldata` is as follows:

`0x51d0eac4000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000f32833125eed6d3b7fbccdcf38139967d4034ba100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011c37937e08000`

> Say if we have a smart contract, we called method1, and then call method2 which contains assembly with calldataload. will this calldataload load the input of method2 or method1?

If those two method calls are different, then the `calldata` for each transaction will be different. The `calldata` for `method1()` will simply be the input params (in the format seen above) for that method, and the `calldata` for `method2()` will simply be the input params for that method.

*If the two methods interact on the contract*, whichever method is called in the transaction will be the method whose `calldata` is used and persists throughout the transaction.

---

Edit, based on flygoing's comment:

`calldataload` will load different data depending on the call frame, and will persist for an individual call frame, but not to the next call frame. E.g. if EOA calls function a on `contract A`, and `contract A` calls `function b` on `contract B`, the calldataload will no longer load the EOA's call data and will instead load the data used in the sub-call frame.

Comment: "calldata is used and persists throughout the transaction" - I think I know what you meant here, but this is msleading. `calldataload` will load different data depending on the call frame, and will persist for an individual call frame, but not to the next call frame. E.g. if EOA calls `function a` on `contract A`, and `contract A` calls `function b` on `contract B`, the `calldataload` will no longer load the EOA's call data and will instead load the data used in the sub-call frame.

Comment: I see. I will update the answer accordingly. If `function a` on `contract A` calls `function b` on `contract A`, the `calldataload` will still be the EOA's call data, correct?

Comment: It depends how it's called, either through a jump (local call, i.e. just doing `b()`) or through a message call (message call, i.e. `this.b()`. The latter, in Solidity, will change the `calldataload`, but the former wont. In Vyper, AFAIK, all calls to local functions (i.e. both `this.b()` and `b()`) create a message call so `calldataload` will change.